# Rewriting only for HTML page requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my htaccess files:

```
Options +FollowSymLink
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-F
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-D
RewriteRule  (.*) index.php [L]
```

I am guessing the above is the reason why my images are not appearing as I am redirecting everything to index.php?

How can I just limit this to HTML files and PHP files?

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.html$ /index.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I get a 500 internal server error for some reason using the above.

Comment: Sorry missed an S. Edited the main post. Drop the RewriteCond as well.